# XML Column Querying Suggestion

Tags: sql, sqlxml

I have a table with 2 billion rows of which one column contains XML data. Actually am writing a SQL to extract data from the XML column ad populate in to another table. it really takes lot of time.. processing 3k rows per second.
My XML query has about 30 columns mostly extracting data with xpath statements like below. Am using SQL server 2012 standard edition, so no table partitioning is possible.

My sql is like below. Can you give some suggestions how I can improve performance.

```
SELECT Id,
    a1 = CASE SortOrder
                        WHEN 0 THEN Contents.value('(/a/Code)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
                        ELSE NULL END,
    a2 = CASE SortOrder
                        WHEN 1 THEN Contents.value('(/a/Code)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
                        ELSE NULL END,
    a3 = Contents.value('(/b/c)[1]', 'varchar(255)'),     
    a4 = Contents.value('(/d/e/f[@category="aa"]/@categoryDate)[1]', 'datetimeOffset'),  
    a5 = Convert(varchar(max),STUFF((SELECT ',' + OTH.value('(.)', 'varchar(150)') 
    FROM Contents.nodes('/d/e/f[@category="g"]/SelectedCategories/SelectedCategory') AS Node(OTH) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) + ' & '
    + ISNULL(Contents.value('(/d/e/f[@category="g"]/Freeform)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), ' ' )
    FROM tbl
```

Adding Primary XML index might help?

Comment: Adding a Primary XML Key should help. I usually see ~10x performance when doing that